# libccv - how to read image from bytes in memory

Tags: python, c, computer-vision, swig

I'm trying to use libccv with Python (I've created wrapper using SWIG). My scenario is the following:

1. I have in-memory image
2. I want to pass this image (bytes) to C function, wrapped for Python with SWIG.
3. C code will process the image with `libccv` functions

Python code:

```
bytes = open("input.jpg","rb").read()
result = ccvwrapper.use_ccv(bytes, 800, 600)
```

C code:

```
int use_ccv(char *bytes, int width, int height){
    int status = 0;
    ccv_enable_default_cache();
    ccv_dense_matrix_t* image = 0;
    ccv_read(bytes, &image, CCV_IO_ANY_RAW, width, height, width * 3);

    if (image != 0)
    {
        //process the image
        ccv_matrix_free(image);
        status = 1;
    }
    ccv_drain_cache();

    return status;
}
```

I've tried a few combinations of `type, rows, cols, scanline` parameters of `ccv_read` but every time I got either **SIGSEV** or the `image` variable was `0`.

I don't want to use `ccv_read` function overload, which takes file path, because I don't want to introduce overhead of writing the image to disk.

What is the proper way of reading the image from memory using libccv?

Comment: The pointer that you are passing to the C function is valid (the *bytes ptr)? I mean, a sanity check could be good, just in case.

Comment: Yes, it's valid. I can write those bytes to back to file using ```fwrite()``` in C function and it produces exactly the same image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, **the trick was to use** `fmemopen()` **function**, to open memory as stream, which further can be read by APIs, which accept `FILE*` pointers.

Full code:

```
int* swt(char *bytes, int array_length, int width, int height){
    ccv_dense_matrix_t* image = 0;

    FILE *stream;
    stream = fmemopen(bytes, array_length, "r");
    if(stream != NULL){
        int type = CCV_IO_JPEG_FILE | CCV_IO_GRAY;
        int ctype = (type & 0xF00) ? CCV_8U | ((type & 0xF00) >> 8) : 0;
        _ccv_read_jpeg_fd(stream, &image, ctype);
    }
    if (image != 0){
       // here we have access to image in libccv format, so any processing can be done
    }
}
```

Usage from Python (after building the C code with SWIG):

```
import ccvwrapper
bytes = open("test_input.jpg", "rb").read()
results = ccvwrapper.swt(bytes, len(bytes), 1024, 1360) # width:1024, height:1360
```

I've explained all of the details in a blog post: http://zablo.net/blog/post/stroke-width-transform-swt-python